# Sum INT values with the same foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

I need to take the following table and show the total InjuryPaymentAmt for each ClaimID for dates in 2018... I use the following code, but I can not get ClaimID1 to output as a single value (as opposed to three)

[image: dataset]
[image: output]

```
Select SUM(InjuryPaymentAmt) as TotalClaims2018, ClaimID
from PersonalInjuryPmt
where InjuryPaymentDate between '2017-12-30' and '2018-12-28' 
group by InjuryPaymentDate, ClaimID;
```

Update - I have a similar table "PropertyClaimPmt" and I am trying to join the tables together, in hopes of a similar result. I want the ClaimIDs in one column, and the total of the claims in the other - but they need to be for 2018. I tried a union, but its dropping one value from one table, and not summing a different value from the other table.

```
Select ClaimID, SUM(PropPaymentAmt) as TotalClaims2018 
from PropertyClaimPmt
    where PropPaymentDate >= '2017-12-30' and PropPaymentDate <='2018-12-28'
        group by ClaimID
Union
Select ClaimID, SUM(InjuryPaymentAmt) as TotalClaims2018
    from PersonalInjuryPmt
        where InjuryPaymentDate >= '2017-12-30' and InjuryPaymentDate < '2018-12-29' 
            group by ClaimID;
```

[Capture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDx1w.jpg)
[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy2t9.jpg)

Comment: Take InjuryPaymentDate out of the group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` specifies the rows in the result set.  Each unique combination of group by keys (that is present in the data) is in the result set, with one combination per row.  Because you want one row per `ClaimId`, that should be the only column in the `GROUP BY`.

I usually put the aggregate key columns first in the `SELECT`, followed by the aggregation expressions:

```
Select ClaimID, SUM(InjuryPaymentAmt) as TotalClaims2018
from PersonalInjuryPmt
where InjuryPaymentDate between '2017-12-30' and '2018-12-28' 
group by ClaimID;
```

Because of confusion between dates with and without a time component, it is safer to write the date logic as:

```
Select ClaimID, SUM(InjuryPaymentAmt) as TotalClaims2018
from PersonalInjuryPmt
where InjuryPaymentDate >= '2017-12-30' and 
      InjuryPaymentDate < '2018-12-29' 
group by ClaimID;
```

This will work even when `InjuryPaymentDate` has a time component.

Comment: Thanks - this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should only group by the `ClaimID`:

```
SELECT   SUM(InjuryPaymentAmt) as TotalClaims2018, ClaimID
FROM     PersonalInjuryPmt
WHERE    YEAR(InjuryPaymentDate) = 2018
GROUP BY ClaimID;
```